# Electric guitar amp won't switch to distortion channel

Tags: amplifiers, electronics, distortion

I have a Peavey Classic 30 combo amp (tubed). There's a channel switch button on the amp that is meant to toggle between the clean and distortion channels. However when I attempt to toggle from clean to distorted, I get no distortion. The tone stays clean. I've had the amp for about 5 years now and it used to work with no problems. How can I get the amp to properly switch to the distortion channel? Is it something I can do myself, or will I need to take it to a music shop?

Comment: @Dom - Yes, all the tubes seem to be good judging by the looks. Some tubes are more illuminated than others, but it seems like that has always been the case.

Comment: Is there maybe a knob on the distortion channel (Gain or something) that isn't turned up enough?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - Yes there is a Gain knob but I've tried twisting all combinations of controls to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

With a couple of my smaller Peaveys, the amp. switch works in conjunction with the footswitch. When the amp. switch is 'on', the footswitch will then toggle between clean/dirty. You may have inadvertently switched the footswitch, which you may or may not usually use.Check the instructions (downloads available) before doing anything drastic. Do not swear at it - amps are very sensitive ...

Comment: So are you saying the amp could "think" that there's a footswitch plugged in?

Comment: I'm saying that if the footswitch is in, it may need switching on.

Comment: I don't own a footswitch.

Comment: Well, it can't be that then ! Lots of Peavey amps have a socket in the back to connect a footswitch for channel change and reverb.

Comment: It does have a port to connect a footswitch, I just don't have one. That's what I meant from my earlier comment. It could be that the amp is acting as though a footswitch is plugged in, even though one isn't. Possible? Maybe? Not sure.

Comment: Until you plug in to that socket, you won't know.It's a TSR (stereo) jack.

Comment: AFAIK, you can test it with a stereo plug by shorting the tip to ground. Google "peavey classic 30 footswitch schematic"